# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml' despite the package already installed

Tags: python, windows

I have a script that returned error at Windows when executing `py C:\updatefile.py "E:\Default\test.dat"`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\update.py", line 4, in <module>
    import lib_TestFolders
  File "C:\update.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

I am using `python 3.5.3`

I have tried to install the lxml,the package is already installed.

```
pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\programme\python35\lib\site-packages
```

the script which intend to copy a file fromnetwork drive to local machine:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import lib_TestFolders

print('\n<<< Update test.dat file >>>')
try:
    destFile = os.path.join(lib_TestFolders.getBasicDataPath(), 'test.dat')
    pFile = ''
    print('    INFO: Getting test.dat from installation folder...')
    TestTestInstallationPath = lib_TestFolders.getInstallationPath('Test Test')
    if not os.path.exists(TestTestInstallationPath):
        TestTestInstallationPath = lib_TestFolders.getInstallationPath('Test Basic')
    pFile = os.path.join(TestTestInstallationPath, 'scripts', 'test.dat')
    if not (pFile.lower().endswith('test.dat') and os.path.isfile(pFile)):
        if len(sys.argv) >= 1:
            pFile = sys.argv[1]
            print('    INFO: Getting test.dat from: ' + pFile)
            if not (pFile.lower().endswith('test.dat') and os.path.isfile(pFile)):
                print('    ERROR: Invalid file: ' + pFile)
                os._exit(1)
        else:
            print('    ERROR: Invalid file: ' + pFile)
            os._exit(1)
    print('    INFO: Copying file [' + pFile + '] to [' + destFile + ']...')
    shutil.copy(pFile, destFile)
    print('    INFO: File copy done...')
except:
    print('EXCEPTION ERROR: ' + str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
```

Comment: Try using `py -m pip install lxml` - it might be a conflict between different versions of Python

Comment: Try also restarting your computer or IDE/Code editor

Comment: i only has one python35 installed.

Comment: i am using windows cmd to run the command